# Wget & Python / No user option

Tags: python, wget

I use the python library `wget`:

```
import wget
wget.download("https://example.com")
```

It gives me the following error:

```
IOError: ('http error', 401, 'Unauthorized', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x10728c0>)
```

This happens because I should use the option of user & password in order to get the files.

Is there any option for that? If not, what is the best way to download a folder in python from external repository with user and password?

Answer (score 2):

You can give username password for basic authentication in URL it self, try below code.

```
import wget
wget.download("https://username:password@example.com/")
```

Comment: Thanks, but it downloads only the __init__.py file, and not the folder itself.

Comment: could you show me url you are trying to download ?

Answer (score -3):

Use ftp instead of http

```
import wget
wget.download("ftp://username:password@example.com/file_path/file_name")
```