# How do I pass username and password with a wget.download() request in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, https, download, wget, file-transfer

To download a file from a web server, I do below -

```
import wget

url = "https:xxxxx/file"

iso_filename = wget.download(url, '/Users/xxxxx/Downloads/')
```

Now, I am trying to download a file from a website which requires authentication.

User credentials involve special characters - @, # etc

I would like to know a way of how to supply username and password in python3 while using wget ?

I would prefer to use wget unless there isn't any other option to overcome this issue.

Any advise would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wget & Python / No user option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386644/wget-python-no-user-option)

Comment: No, it works with simple username password, but doesn't works with credentials like -

uid - abc@xxx.com
psw - xyz@

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL: Username with @](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050877/url-username-with)

Comment: No, unfortunately it didn't helped -

uid = user.name@website.com
psw = password@1234

Below is the sample code which returns an exception -

filename = wget.download('https://user.name%40website.com : password%401234@website.com/bin/support/download?sid=u0ijav0to9j6u', '/Users/localmachine/Downloads/')

Comment: If you are using basic auth you can use `https://<username>:<password>@host.com/path`

Comment: I am not sure if we can use this with wget.download() as it says the syntax isn't valid for the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally gave up on using wget.download(), what worked for me is scp, explained as below -

```
sshpass -f 'path to psw file' scp -r user@10.X.X.X:/file_path /path_to dowload_file
```

ex:

```
sshpass -f 'usr/bin/psw.txt' scp -r user@10.X.X.X:/usr/bin/ubuntu.iso /remote/user/iso
```

psw.txt to pass password in a file to avoid been listed in bash history etc...